# numpy array reshape adding dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

Ok I am a (very) novice Python user, but I am trying to translate a piece of Python code into R, and I have run into a confusing problem with array reshaping.

Lets make some example data:

```
X1 = np.array([[-0.047, -0.113, 0.155, 0.001],
        [0.039, 0.254, 0.054, 0.201]], dtype=float)

In:X1
Out:
array([[-0.047, -0.113, 0.155, 0.001],
        [0.039, 0.254, 0.054, 0.201]])
In:X1.shape
Out: (2,4)
```

Ok so I've made a 2D array with 2 rows and 4 columns. I'm happy with this. The confusion arises with this line of code:

```
X2 = X1.reshape((2, -1, 1))

In: X2
Out:
array([[[-0.047],
        [-0.113],
         [0.155],
         [0.001]],

         [0.039],
         [0.254],
         [0.054],
         [0.201]]])

In: X2.shape
Out: (2, 4, 1)
```

So I know that I have added an extra dimension (which I think is the 3rd digit `1` in the reshape command), but I don't understand what else this had done. The shape implies it is still got 2 rows and 4 columns, but clearly something else is changed. Again my motivation here is to do the same operation in R, but until I know I understand what I've transformed here I am stuck. (Forgive me if this is an awful question I only started Python yesterday!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By `reshape(2, -1, 1)` you have not just added added a new dimension. You have said

```
* the 1st dimension should be of size 2
* the 3rd dimension should be of size 1
* the 2nd should be whatever remains
```

so, the only valid option if 4. If you just want to add a new dimension to an existing matrix, you should do something like `x[:, np.newaxis, :]` (exact usage depends on what you want the output format to be)

Comment: Thats really helpful thank you. In my example does since `X1` had dimension (2, 4) and `X2` has dimension (2,4,1) - why when I print them does `X1` shows the rows with cells side by side, while` X2` shows the individual cells one under another?

Comment: Well, printing 3D data in 2D space is confusing indeed. `X2` has 3 opening brackets, so the data you get are ordered along the 3rd dimension, not along rows. For example, try printing `X2[0, 0, :]` the make it clearer.

Comment: ok thanks @blue_note - this has been really helpful. Helped me to figure out that the problem is not in these steps, but with later array algebra being handled differently - many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 different ways of adding a dimension to a 2D array.

You should try different combinations to understand the use of `reshape`. Try the following:

```
import numpy as np

X1 = np.array([[-0.047, -0.113, 0.155, 0.001],
        [0.039, 0.254, 0.054, 0.201]], dtype=float)

X2 = X1.reshape((1, 2, -1))
print(X2)

>[[[-0.047 -0.113  0.155  0.001]
   [ 0.039  0.254  0.054  0.201]]]

X3 = X1.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
print(X3)

>[[[-0.047 -0.113]]
  [[ 0.155  0.001]]
  [[ 0.039  0.254]]
  [[ 0.054  0.201]]]
```